# data.stackexchange.com login and errors in query

Tags: support, data-explorer

I'm getting a pop-up on data.stackexchange.com (all sub sites) that says

> "MiniProfiler requires JQuery"

Also when running any Query ( I am logged in) I get the following:

```
{"error":"All parameters must be set!"}
```

This happens on all query's

Using Chrome 13.0.7

Also is there a reason why the login @ data.stackexchange.com is not tied into the main stackoverflow.com and it's network?

Update:

Tested with Firefox (5.0) ( thinking it might be chrome).

Same error `MiniProfiler requires JQuery`.

But when running a query I get a download dialog with:

> you have chosen to open
>
> **1**
>
> which is a: application/json from http://data.stackexchange.com
>
> what should firefox do with this file? etc...

Comment: Maybe they're running the new dump now? Everything is over a month out of date.

Comment: @agf I was able to run a few queries just a minute ago.

Comment: Do you have something like NoScript running?  That would explain why your browser would be rejecting the jQuery.  Also, is your user id (the number in the upper right of your profile, not your screenname, though this should fill in for you when you are logged into SEDE) correct?

Comment: No, tested in firefox and chrome. Firefox acts even stranger Ill add to OP.

Comment: try again, just deployed a new round

Answer (score 3):

[status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro) for me; possibly it's fixed already. `data.stackexchange.com` is disconnected from the rest of the network because it started out as an [independent project](http://code.google.com/p/stack-exchange-data-explorer/) by [Sam Saffron](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/17174/waffles), before he was [hired to work for Stack Exchange](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/welcome-stack-overflow-valued-associate-00008/). Now it's an official tool, but it's never really been integrated into the rest of the network

Comment: Not fixed for me , just tested in Firefox and IE, same results.